# C# Is there a way of implementing interfaces for classes from dlls?

Tags: c#, dll, interface, tdd

I'm using a dll with a lot of classes. I'd like to implement dinamically interfaces for these classes, then I can unit test them by mock.

Is there a way of doing it?

Example:

The dll has a class Comunicator

```
public class Comunicator
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        //execute something
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this class implementing the interface below dinamically?

```
public interface IComunicator
{
    void Execute();
}
```

This way I want that the property below

```
public IComunicator Comunicator{ get; set; }
```

Be able to understand this assignment

```
Comunicator = new Comunicator();
```

Comment: This question is unclear.

Comment: What happened when you tried implementing an interface from dll? Have you?

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a better explanation of my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of doing this class implementing the interface below dynamically?

Short Answer: **NO**

If the dll is a 3rd party library then there is nothing you can do to modify that class as you have no control over it.

You could however create your own classes and abstraction to encapsulate the 3rd party dependency.

You create your desired interface

```
public interface IComunicator {
    void Execute();
}
```

And either using encapsulation

```
public class MyCommunicator : ICommunicator {
    private readonly Communicator communicator = new communicator();

    public void Execute() {
        communicator.Execute();
    }
}
```

or inheritance (*if the class is not sealed*)

```
public class MyCommunicator : Communicator, ICommunicator {

}
```

This way the property below

```
public IComunicator Comunicator{ get; set; }
```

Will be able to understand this assignment

```
obj.Comunicator = new MyComunicator();
```